# Does zeromq provide TCP security while communicating to nodejs apps?

Tags: node.js, tcp, zeromq

I have integrated zeromq in 5 applications those are running on nodejs and nginx proxy. I want to know the best way to secure the tcp communication between 0mq and nodejs app - I am mostly using PUB SUB  method.

Currently for security I am using req rep method to share a key with queue id before any connection. this key I am using into SUB.
What are the best standard for zeromq tcp security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZAP CURVE for nodejs zmq lib.

There are few libraries those are in beta but I have implemented Curve Machenism it is working fine no breaking issues
you can use REQ REP also with ZAP module. But best I felt CURVE machenisim.

https://github.com/msealand/zmq-zap.node/tree/master/examples

http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:26/CURVEZMQ

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography

Just go through documentation  and if you face any problem while implementing it please post separate question.